# Why doesn't md-tooltip accept line breaks?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

How can I add line breaks in my `md-tooltip` content if `{{row.entity.comment}}` is too large?

```
<md-tooltip class="large" md-direction="top">
  <span class="tooltip-text">{{row.entity.comment}}</span>
</md-tooltip>
```

Comment: Using `word-wrap: break-word` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `word-wrap` to the `md-tooltip`class

```
.md-tooltip {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

Keep in mind that the `md-tooltip`is set to fixed height of `22px`. 
You could change the `height` to `auto` to prevent this.

```
.md-tooltip {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Try without the `.md-content` subselector

Comment: Same result with
md-tooltip {
  height: auto !important;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
}

Comment: Sorry i had forgotten the `.` before the `md-tooltip` . http://www.imageno.com/6pvi5mx9j5s8pic.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted solution, I also had to override the angular .md-tooltip `white-space: nowrap`

```
.md-tooltip {
    height: auto !important;
    white-space: normal;
}
```